permission for appear on top suddenly stopped after updating target SDK android 14
After updating android 14, we facing a critical issue regarding to this update.
we build a screen lock app which need a full permission to access for foreground and background, but, after updating our targeting SDK project to android 14 we recognise that this permission suddenly stopped after couple of hours. and we received a warning message from google play store that this version of apk wasn't supported android 14.
would you please help us to solve this issue to finalise this project and published it to public.
I tried to implement workmanager but still the background and foreground srvice stopped after couple of hour..
